# NSURL OData URL

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I am passing my OData URL to NSURL like this

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://localhost/odata/Venues?$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime) eq 9 and month(DateTime) eq 3 and year(DateTime) eq 2020)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f: day(f/DateTime) eq 9 and month(f/DateTime) eq 3 and year(f/DateTime) eq 2020)"];
```

This URL is not accepted by NSURL, it is becoming NULL

When I give URL like this

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://google.com"];
```

Then NSURL is accepting the URL... I would like to know how to pass my data URL to NSURL.

Comment: Your URL contains several characters that must be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL contains several characters which need to be escaped. That's absolutely not how URLs work and thus the method `initWithString` is failing and returning NULL...

For the majority of the times I've encountered a situation in which I needed to escape a URL the method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` was more than enough since they were relatively short URLs. Nonetheless, yours is a URL with a lot of characters which this method doesn't particularly like. (This includes slash `/` and ampersand `&`).

For this particular scenario probably the following approach would yield best results whilst keeping it simple.

```
NSString* unencodedURLString = @"https://localhost/odata/Venues?$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime) eq 9 and month(DateTime) eq 3 and year(DateTime) eq 2020)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f: day(f/DateTime) eq 9 and month(f/DateTime) eq 3 and year(f/DateTime) eq 2020)";

NSString* urlString = [unencodedURLString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Please let us know if this worked for you...